# csrun loses executable from .csx package

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles

I am having a hard time with a seemingly simple Azure program.

My exercise is to create WorkerRole that spawns "helloworld.exe"
- which does just that - prints "hello world" and exits.

I am using Visual Studio to create a project,
then added new folder to project solution "bin2" where I put hello.exe 
using menu option "Add Existing Item".

then created local storage bin2 in ServiceDefinition.csdef:

so I can find my executable with RoleEnvironment:

string baseDir = RoleEnvironment.GetLocalResource("bin2").RootPath.Replace('\', '/');
string command = Path.Combine(baseDir, @"hello.exe");

then ran cspack.exe to create .csx directory.

Resulting .csx package got hello.exe in the correct location: 
WorkerRole1.csx\roles\WorkerRole1\approot\bin2\hello.exe

then I started local development fabric with csrun.exe and get error from the parent process that bin2/hello.exe is missing.

Do I need to do something else to make csrun to copy hello.exe into "bin2".
Any ideas?

Thank you in advance,
Ivgard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure I answered this question already (<strike>probably</strike> [on the MSDN forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazuredevelopment/thread/6798fdc3-2718-4329-b001-97be2a40adc8))? But the local resource you declare will give you a path entirely different from where you're putting your hello.exe. When you add the file to your project, it gets included with the rest of the code for your role. When you look up the local resource, you get a path to an empty directory which you can use to write and read data. Those two are completely separate and unrelated locations.

If you want to find your hello.exe that's under bin2, just look for the relative path, or use %RoleRoot%\approot\bin2 (or maybe it's %RoleRoot%\approot\bin\bin2?).

Comment: Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%RoleRoot%/approot");